# How does one add a single file to a perforce repository?

Tags: bash, perforce

I have a large shared drive (~500Gb, 20k files, samba/afs). I would like to add all the files in there to a perforce repository.

I imagine adding/committing them all in one fell swoop is not a good idea.

How would I then to do that? Add/commit one by one? And would that ensure that the files on the shared drive are NOT locked?

I am comfortable with bash or perl, and this would have to happen under Mac OS X.

Bonus question: would the method also allow checking in the same files if they get changed on the shared drive via a cron job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on your hardware what Perforce can handle. You should not likely have to add the files one at a time, however. [This article](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Adding-a-Directory-Tree) here shows how to add whole directories at once:

Regarding your bonus question, yes you can easily handle files modified by your cron job by using the reconcile method. See the section 'Reconcile through the Command Line' in [this article](http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Working-Disconnected-From-The-Perforce-Server).